# Opening multiple files with openFileInput(Uri) and multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, file, android-studio

I'm trying to open multiple files with multiple threads using `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri)` but it seems that when reading, all the threads read from the same file. I've tried making the method `synchronized` but did not work. Here is the code:

```
private String getVideoData(Uri uri) {
        String res = null;
        MyActivity activity = ActivityTransferer.getInstance().getActivity();

        try { 
            InputStream fis = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            if (fis != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

                int read = fis.read(bytes);

                while (read != -1) {
                    byteOutputStream.write(bytes);
                    read = fis.read(bytes);
                }

                byte[] data = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();

                res = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);

                fis.close();
                byteOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return res;
}
```

And the code that calls this method is:

```
private EncryptedFile encryptUri(Uri uri) {
        EncryptedFile res = null;
        MyActivity activity = ActivityTransferer.getInstance().getActivity();

        String type = activity.getContentResolver().getType(uri);

        if (type != null) {
            String data;
            System.out.println("Path: " + uri.getPath());
            System.out.println("Type: " + type);
            if (type.startsWith("video")) {

                data = getVideoData(uri);
                res = new EncryptedVideo();
                System.out.println("Data: " + data);
                res.encrypt(data, password);

            }
            else {

                data = getImageData(uri);
                res = new EncryptedPicture();
                res.encrypt(data, password);

            }
        }

        return res;
}
```

which is called from:

```
while (!toEncrypt.isEmpty()) {
        file = toEncrypt.poll();

        encrypted = encryptUri(file);

        result.add(encrypted);
}
```

Printing the first 100 bytes of `byte[] data = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();` I get:

`I/System.out: 0-0-0-24-102-116-121-112-109-112-52-50-0-0-0-0-109-112-52-50-105-115-111-109-0-0-0-24-98-101-97-109-1-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-0-0-0-0-0--126-6-109-111-111-118-0-0-0-108-109-118-104-100-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-88-0-0--86-30-0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-`

and on other thread:

`I/System.out: 0-0-0-24-102-116-121-112-109-112-52-50-0-0-0-0-109-112-52-50-105-115-111-109-0-0-0-24-98-101-97-109-1-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-0-0-0-0-0--126-6-109-111-111-118-0-0-0-108-109-118-104-100-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-88-0-0--86-30-0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-`

Printing with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    System.out.print(data[i] + "-");
```

with Base64 encoding (also same o both obviously):

```
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
```

By the way, `ActivityTransferer.getInstance().getActivity()` returns the current Context.

Please if you could help me I'd appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Comment: You do not show where your threads are. If your threads are calling `getVideoData()`, then make sure that you are not somehow using the same `uri` value for all of those threads.

Comment: @CommonsWare this method is being called from the thread itself, that's why it does not makes sense to me why it's reading the same file in all the threads. And yes, the `uri` is different always, I've tested it.

Comment: "it seems... all the threads read from the same file." How exactly did you make this determination? Please show the code that calls `getVideoData()`.

Comment: @greeble31 just added it. I know that reads the same file, because when I add the videos it's always the same, also if you print `byte[] data = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();` you'll get always the same.

Comment: Could you humor me, and add the printout to your question?

Comment: @greeble31 haha ok, it's done, only the first 100 bytes.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced this code is malfunctioning. How do you know you've dumped enough data to get to a unique point? mp4 files may have lengthy headers, depending how they were made, they may be identical for several KB. What you've dumped so far is not getting into the media data, yet. I would suggest you A.) Use checksum, B.) compare based on total size, or C.) substitute known input data for each unique file (something trivial, like all 0xAA, 0xBB, etc.)

Comment: @greeble31 Ok, I think I am going to try with what you suggested. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

The solution in this case is to make the method `private String getVideoData(Uri uri)` static and synchronized (`private static synchronized String getVideoData(Uri uri)`). I think the problem is that some operation used in the code is using an static method or variable. So by making the method static and synchronized it will wait for other threads to finish before starting the operation.

In this case, `InputStream fis = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` is probably what is causing the problem.